# Unpacking a std::array

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

I tried to unpack a `std::array` via `std::tie`:

```
#include <tuple>
#include <array>

int main() {
    std::array<int, 3> arr = {1, 2, 3};
    int a, b, c;
    std::tie(a, b, c) = arr;
    return 0;
}
```

This works in clang, but fails to compile in g++ 5.4: `no match for ‘operator=’`. Compile options are `-std=c++11`.

1. Why does this work in clang but not g++?
2. How can I portably unpack a `std::array`, like one might unpack a tuple?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Probably something additional provided by `libc++` implementation ?

Comment: [Doesn't compile in Visual Studio 2015 either](http://rextester.com/BXYD49474)

Comment: This does not compile with versions of clang beyond 3.2.  [See here](https://godbolt.org/g/IJzo2c) (add in the `-std=c++11`, as the link seems to lose the command-line option)

Comment: This is a libc++ extension. @PaulMcKenzie You need `-stdlib=libc++`.

Comment: g++ 5.4 is quite old 2016 and this feature is from c++17 https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support/17#C.2B.2B14_library_features gcc 7 is required.

Answer (score 8):

I would create dedicated function to transform array to tuple. C++14 code could look as follows:

```
template <class T, std::size_t N, std::size_t... Is>
auto unpack_impl(std::array<T, N> &arr, index_sequence<Is...>) -> decltype(std::make_tuple(arr[Is]...)) {
    return std::make_tuple( arr[Is]... );
}

template <class T, std::size_t N>
auto unpack(std::array<T, N> &arr) -> decltype(unpack_impl(arr, make_index_sequence<N>{})) {
    return unpack_impl(arr, make_index_sequence<N>{});
}
```

And then use it like:

```
std::array<int, 3> arr = {{1, 2, 3}};
int a, b, c;
std::tie(a, b, c) = unpack(arr);
```

In c++11 you would need however to implement `integer_sequence` as it does not come out of the box in the standard...

[Here](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/88ieeDpVcrTZz4cn) you can find complete c++11 solution.

**Edit:**

If an array contains some more complex objects you might want to avoid unnecessary copy. To do that instead of `make_tuple` you may use tuple of const references or if the constness doesn't bother you you could simple tie array elements up:

```
template <class T, std::size_t N, std::size_t... Is>
auto unpack_impl(std::array<T, N> &arr, index_sequence<Is...>) -> decltype(std::tie( arr[Is]... )) {
    return std::tie( arr[Is]... );
}
```

**Edit2:**

[This one](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/8B7JeIw5NjkboM9A) compiles also on VS

Comment: Great! by the way you missed `std::` for `index_sequence` and `make_index_sequence`. and an include for `<utility>` . 
All in all this is a treat for me and thank you for that :)

Comment: I use `std::array<T, N> &&arr` in both functions  and then pass it as `std::forward<std::array<T, N>>(arr)`
Because you might wane unpack a temporary value from say a function call.

Answer (score 0):

Structured binding with C++17 (also works in Visual Studio 2017~):

```
std::array<int, 3> arr{1, 2, 3};
auto & [a, b, c] = arr;
```

[Try in godbolt.org](https://godbolt.org/z/n9cTWa5jo)