# C++: set multiple variables from array

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, c++14, c++17

I have the following program:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int array[] = {1, 2, 3};
    int a = array[0],
        b = array[1],
        c = array[2];

    cout << c << endl;
}
```

This prints 3, so far so good. But I wonder if there is a more elegant syntax for declaring multiple variables from an array at once. For example (just an idea, does not compile):

```
int [a, b, c] = array;
```

Is there any feature like this in C++ or one of the new standards? I can't be the only one looking it.

Alternatively: what is your most elegant way to set multiple variables from an array at once?

Comment: I think it would be nice to tell us more what you want to do with those variables or what do you to do after that

Comment: As you've specified c++11, i'd take a look at `std::tie`

Comment: Is there a reason you cannot use the array directly? Is an array really the most appropriate structure for your actual problem? Arrays are intended for a list of items. If the data is instead a collection of related data, a `class` or `struct` is more appropriate.

Comment: Depends: In my project I have a data array to begin with (different author). But in general I agree, a struct would have been the better choice obviously.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In C++17 you can use [**structured bindings**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding) - their syntax is very similar to what you have posted:

```
auto [a, b, c] = array;
```

[**live example on wandbox**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/66i92jJ5vEUHuEsr)

---

The closest thing to that in C++11/14 is [`std::tie`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie), but it unfortunately doesn't work with arrays: it only supports `std::tuple`. You could however use metaprogramming to create an utility that creates a tuple from an array, and then use `tie` on it. There's [a possible implementation in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40958644/598696) by W.F..

Comment: Wow, that was fast! Good to see this is actually coming. Now let's hope the C++17 standard is finalized fast. :)

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking for is called [structured bindings](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding) and it will be available in C++17.  They will allow you to create references to the elements of arrays, certain classes/structs and tuple like objects.

Since your looking for a pre C++17 solution really the best you can do is use [`std::tie`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie) to construct tuples that refer to what you want to assign like

```
int array[] = {1, 2, 3};
int a, b, c;
std::tie(a, b, c) = std::tie(array[0], array[1], array[2])
```

But that really doesn't save you much.